# Kafka consumers in consumer group reading from different Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have two Kafka clusters A and B. We are migrating the workload from cluster A to cluster B. While performing this migration at some point we want consumer to read from both the cluster being part of same consumer-group.

Example:
There is `topic-1` in cluster A and `topic-1` in cluster B. We have consumer group called `topic-1-cg`. During migration we will instantiate consumers in cluster B with same group-id i.e. topic-1-cg. This will make the consumer group having consumers pointing to both clusters i.e. few consumers are reading from cluster A and few from cluster B. Both consumers are instantiated with same consumer-group ID.

My question is, is this consumer configuration allowed to use? I am not able to simulate multi-cluster setup locally.

Comment: It's very easy to create multiple kafka clusters locally. You only need two brokers that aren't connected. What have you tried?

Comment: Have tried it, it has not seem to work. Wanted to confirm with the community if this really don't work.

Comment: It can work. Feel free to create a new post with what exactly you'd tried

Answer (score 2):

No, this setup with not result in consumers reading from both the clusters.

When you have 2 different clusters, they do not talk to each other and that is why they don't know if the same consumer group name is being used in a different consumer group.

So even if you have same topic name and use same consumer group name in 2 different clusters, they will not result in consuming from both clusters.

Comment: More specifically, `__consumer_offsets` topic is unique across each cluster, in combination with the consumed topics